# How can i sleep the execution of each iteration of for loop in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to sleep before each iteration in this for loop.I tried sleep() which is not working.Before each notification i have to make a time delay.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; ++$i) {


echo '<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) 
{

 var title_txt = "' .$output[$i] .'";
 var body_txt = "' . $output1[$i] .'";
 var Img_url = "' . $output2[$i] .'";


    window.desktop_notify;

    desktop_notify= function(title_data,body_data,myImg)
    {
       var options =
       {
            title: title_data,
            options: 
            {
                body: body_data,
                icon: myImg,
                lang: "en-US",
                onClick: nav_topage
            }
        };
        jQuery("#easyNotify").easyNotify(options);
    };
    desktop_notify(title_txt,body_txt,Img_url);
  })

  </script>';
 }
```

Comment: Do that in JS not in PHP.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? I feel that this could be done with JSON rather that looping this with PHP

Comment: I dont think you want to sleep the for loop what you want is a `callback`

Comment: i want to have a time delay in displaying the notifications